# Finding maximum arc length when area is fixed

Tags: calculus, control-theory, optimal-control

I'm currently working on the problem of finding the function with minimum arc length when the area between itself and the x-axis is fixed.

More formally, we have to find f(t) such that
$$
\text{minimizes}~\int_0^T \sqrt{1+f'(t)^2}\, dt \\
\text{subject to}~f(0)= f(T)=0~\text{and} \int_0^T f(t)\,dt = M
$$

I tried to solve it using Pontryagin Maximum Principle,
but I can't get the closed form solution.

Can anyone help me?
Thank you

Comment: Shouldn't the upper bound of the second integral be T instead of t?

Comment: I think you should use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculus_of_variations .

Comment: @Divide1918 Thanks. I changed it

Comment: @NN2 Thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: This is one of most ancient problems in Calculus of Variations, It is known as Dido's problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can formulate it in a form that can be solved by Pontryagin Maximum Principle using

\begin{align}
\min_u &\int_0^T \sqrt{1 + u^2}\,dt, \\
\text{s.t.}&
\begin{bmatrix}
\dot{x}_1 \\ \dot{x}_2
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
u \\ x_1
\end{bmatrix}, \\
& x_1(0) = x_2(0) = x_1(T) = 0,\ x_2(T) = M.
\end{align}

Namely $x_1(t)$ is equivalent to $f(t)$ and thus $f'(t) = u(t)$, and $x_2(T)$ is equivalent to the integral of $f(t)$ from zero to $T$.